# What field should I use to get current block number

Tags: ledger

https://horizon.stellar.org/ returns `history_latest_ledger` and `core_latest_ledger`.

Which field should be used to get the current block number? Which one is more reliable? Diffs?

I assume `history_latest_ledger` is the last ledger saved in horizon DB, isn't? Wouldn't it be better to use this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two components involved in running a stellar backend. The one is `stellar-core` which manages peer to peer data propagation, the other one is `stellar-horizon` which gets and prepares that data from core for convenient access.

- `core_latest_ledger` is the latest existing ledger that stellar-core is aware of (it's p2p, it might as well lag behind the network)
- `history_latest_ledger` is the latest ledger that horizon has already ingested from stellar-core

So it's safe to say that:

`real current ledger >= core_latest_ledger >= history_latest_ledger`.

If you want to query more details then rely on `history_latest_ledger`, because that's the latest ledger you will get processed details for from horizon anyways.